# How to get video url with youtube api(v3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube-data-api

I'm working in node on a server and I'm trying to use the YouTube Api to get a video url. The particular url isn't important, this is more of just an exercise. As far as I can tell with the docs, the best way to find a particular video is if it is associated with a channel or user. IE,

1. query the api with a username(GoogleDevelopers for example)
2. get it's channel id
3. query again to get that channels playlists
4. search a particular playlist to get a playlist item
5. given a playlistid, search with that to get items(each should represent a video)
6. item ids have a `videoId` field, search with that
7. get video info, but no url?

However, when I get to that point I feel like there should be a url to that video. The though process would be to send this url back to a front end to allow it to use some library to render the video.

**QUESTION**: Is there a better way to do this? If not, where am I missing the video URL,

Comment: Is this for the Data API yeah?  Is anything else included in the return when you set `part=snippet` in the request?

Comment: Yes, and yeah a couple of other fields(depending on which query I'm running) like `kind`, `etag`, `nextPageToken` etc.

Comment: sweet, you should also have the `id` object with the `videoId` hopefully, and my answer will make sense

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your return you should get a `videoId`:

```
"id": 
{
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "videoId": "BsLvIF5c7NU"
}
```

**edit**:  the return is actually just the `id`:

```
"id": "BsLvIF5c7NU"
```

All you need to do is just append that to the standard url no?:

```
var url = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${result.id.videoId}`;
```

Does that make sense?

**edit**: You could also use `part=contentDetails` in which case the `id` is under:

`result.items.id`

Depending on what you use in the `part` param will change up the layout of what's returned.

Hope that helps you, dude.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @dmccallum83 is correct.

If for some reason you can't (don't want to) concatenate strings -

```
const youtube = require("googleapis").youtube('v3');

async function getVideoUrl(videoId) {
  const res = await youtube.videos.list({
    part: "snippet,contentDetails",
    id: videoId,
  });

  const video = res.data.items[0];

  return video.snippet.resourceId.url;
}

const videoId = "YOUR_VIDEO_ID";

const videoUrl = await getVideoUrl(videoId);
```

Get the video id from the response of your upload request and use that to get the video details using the `videos.list` method which will return a list of videos, including the video url.

Comment: Neither the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) nor the type definitions show `url` as a property of `resourceId`